# Conditional update for MongoDB (Meteor)

Tags: mongodb, meteor

TLDR: Is there a way I can conditionally update a Meteor Mongo record inside a collection, so that if I use the id as a selector, I want to update if that matches and only if the revision number is greater than what already exists, or perform an upsert if there is no id match?

I am having an issue with updates to server side Meteor Mongo collections, whereby it seems the added() function callback in the Observers is being triggered on an upsert.

Here is what I am trying to do in a nutshell.

- My meteor js app boots and then connects to an endpoint, fetching data and then upserting it into the collection.

  ```
  collection.update({'sys.id': item.sys.id}, item, {upsert: true});
  ```
- The 'sys.id' selector checks to see if the item exists, and then updates if it does or adds if it does not.
- I have an observer monitoring the above collection, which then acts when an item has been added/updated to the collection.

  collection.find({}).observeChanges({
      added: this.itemAdded.bind(this),
      changed: this.itemChanged.bind(this),
      removed: this.itemRemoved.bind(this)
  });
- The first thing that puzzles me is that when the app is closed and then booted again, the 'added()' callback is fired when the collection is observed. What I would hope to happen is that the changed() callback is fired.

Going back to my original update - is it possible in Mongo to conditionally update something, so you have the selector, then the item, but only perform the update when another condition is met?

```
// Incoming item 
var item = {
    sys: {
       id: 1,
       revision: 5
    }
};

collection.update({'sys.id': item.sys.id, 'sys.revision': {$gt: item.sys.revision}, item, {upsert: true});
```

If you look at the above code, what this is going to do is try to match the sys.id which is fine, but then the revisions will of course be different which means the update function will see it as a different document and then perform a new insert, thus creating duplicate data.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

To your main question:

What you want is called `findAndModify`. First, look for the the document meeting the specs, and then update accordingly. This is a really powerful idea because if you did it in 2 queries, the document you found could be deleted/updated before you got to update it. Luckily for you, someone made a package (I really wish this existed a year ago!) https://github.com/fongandrew/meteor-find-and-modify

If you were to do this without using `findAndModify` you'd have to use javascript to find the doc, see if it matches your criteria, and then update it. In your use case, this would probably work, but there will always be that "what if" in the back of your mind.

Regarding `observeChanges`, the added is called each time the local minimongo receives a document (it's just reading what the DDP is telling it). Since a refresh will delete your local collection, you have to *add* those docs one by one. What you could do is wait until all `added` callbacks have fired, and then run your server method. In doing so, you get a ton of adds, and then a couple more changes will trickle in afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

As Matt K said, you want [findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/).  There are some gotchas to be aware of:

- findAndModify is about 100x slower than a find followed by an update.  Find+modify is, obviously, not atomic and so won't do what you need, but be aware of the speed hit.  (This is based off experience with MongoDB v2.4, so run some benchmarks to confirm under your own version.)
- If your query matches multiple items, findAndModify will only act on the first one.  In this case, you're querying on a unique id, but be aware of the issue for future use.
- findAndModify will return the document after doing its thing, but by default it returns the pre-modification version.  If you want the modified one, you need to pass the 'new: true' in your query.

Comment: Wow, had no idea it was that slow! So we're talking like 100-200ms to complete the write? If the query field is indexed does it make a difference? Seems crazy that it would take that long just to toggle a document-level lock, but assuming that's the bottleneck, I bet wired-tiger improves that. Would love to read more if you've got a link.

Comment: Keep in mind that I got those numbers off of 2.4, before WiredTiger was around and document-level locking wasn't a thing.  Back in the ancient stone age of 2.4, collection-level locking was still the new awesome.   Take it with a grain of salt until you do your own benchmarks.